# Absolute positioning of SVG causes the inner path elements to move outside their containing element

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I have a simple CollapseIcon React component that is essentially two SVG paths (forming an arrow) wrapped by a Circle styled-component.

[image: CollapseIcon]

It works perfectly anywhere I put it on the page...unless I choose to use postion: absolute on it when laying it out. For example, I need to align it in the top right of its container. I tried `position: absolute` (with `top: 0` and `right: 0`), and I also tried `float: right` with `margin-top: -50px`. In both cases, the arrow migrated outside of the Circle bounds.

[image: broken icon]

Here's the simplified React code for the icon:

```
return (
      <Circle  justify="center" alignItems="center"
          onClick={toggleSelect}
          name="collapse"
          {...props}
        >
          <Icon viewBox="0 0 18 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            {...props}
          >
            <g id="Style-Guide" strokeWidth="1" fill="none" fillRule="evenodd" strokeLinecap="round">
              <g id="Style-Guide---Elements" transform="translate(-198.000000, -3941.000000)" stroke="#686868" strokeWidth="2">

                <RotateGroup {...props} id="Collapse-Arrow-Small">
                  <Path {...props} d="M0.727272727,7.33333333 L8.03627318,0.633416253" id="Line-2"></Path>
                  <Path {...props} d="M8,7.33333333 L15.3090005,0.633416253" id="Line-2-Copy" transform="translate(11.636364, 4.000000) scale(-1, 1) translate(-11.636364, -4.000000) "></Path>
                </RotateGroup>
              </g>
            </g>
          </Icon>
        </Circle>
    )

const Circle = styled(FlexContainer)`
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  border: 2px solid ${colors.primary700};

const Path = styled.path`
  fill: none;
  stroke: ${colors.primary700};
`;

const Icon = styled.svg`
  width: 18px;
  height: 10px;

  &:disabled ${Path} {
    stroke: ${colors.primary300};
  }
`
```

And this is where I am attempting to position the icon:

```
  <Section flexDirection="column">
    <SectionTitle>My Food Preferences</SectionTitle>
    <Collapsible trigger={<StyledCollapseIcon/>}>
      <FoodPrefsForm />
    </Collapsible>
  </Section>

const StyledCollapseIcon = styled(CollapseIcon)`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0

  ${'' /* float: right;
  margin-top: -50px; */}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

`absolute` positioning is absolute, *relative* to the nearest `position: relative` ancestor. Give the circle `position: relative` and see if that fixes it.

CSS Tricks has a [great article that explains this](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

Comment: The Circle component is a descendant of the StyledCollapseIcon component that sets the `position: absolute`. But I tried setting all of the descendants to position: relative as well as to position: absolute and neither way helped.